# association where clause with array cakephp 3

Tags: filtering, cakephp-3.0, where-clause, query-builder

Basically what i want to do is write this query with cakephp 3 query builder :

```
SELECT * FROM question as q innerjoin answers as a where q.question = $question AND a.id NOT IN = $avoidedIDs
```

codes for table class

```
    <?php
namespace App\Model\Table;


use Cake\ORM\Table;
use App\Model\Entity\Comlib;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class ComlibsTable extends Table {

public function initialize(array $config) {
    parent::initialize($config);
 $this->table('questions');
// join the tables 
$this->hasMany('Answers' , [
'foreignKey' => 'question_id'
]);



    }

public function LFA( $live_req) {
$query = $this->find()->where(['question' => $live_req])->contain(['Answers'])->LIMIT(6);
$query = $query->toArray();

//include 5 answer
return $query;

    }
    public function LFM($theid , $avoidedIDs, $question )
    {
    $query = $this->find()->where(['question' => $question])->contain(['Answers' => function($q){
    return $q
    ->where(['Answers.id NOT IN' => $avoidedIDs] );
    }
    ]);
    $query = $query->toArray();
    debug($query);
    return $query;

    }
}
```

the error that i get is : Impossible to generate condition with empty list of values for field (Answers.id).
but when i print_r($avoidedIDs) i get the values that i passed so im sure that $avoidedIDs is not empty , at least not out of contain function and thats what makes it more complicated for me, but when i put ONE number instead of my variable it will execute , if i put 1,2,3,4 still it will execute only the first one!
what am i doing WRONG for the past 2 days ?????
tnx for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are trying to use $avoidedIDs in an anonymous function (Closure) call, which is not available there.

You should make it available for the function.

```
->contain(['Answers' => function($q) use ($avoidedIDs){..}
```

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be passed to the use language construct.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php